Sort output in bash based on character count not including spaces, but retain the spaces in output
Given the following contents of file:
a b c 
abcde
ab cd ef
abcdefg
a
a b

I want to rearrange the output based on the number of non-space characters, but retain the spaces when the output is given. Additionally, I need this to be a single command, not something that I put into a script.
Pretty much everything I try ends up like this:
cat file.txt |awk '{ count=gsub(/ /,""); print length($0), $0 }' | sort

1 a
2 ab
3 abc
5 abcde
6 abcdef
7 abcdefg

Which does give me the correct count and sort, but it also removes the spaces from the original output, which I do not want. The desired output would be
1 a 
2 a b
3 a b c 
5 abcde
6 ab cd ef
7 abcdefg


Applying the Decorate-Sort-Undecorate idiom with any awk:
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{print length() - gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"&"), NR, $0}' file |
    sort -n -k1,1 -k2,2 | cut -f3-
a
a b
a b c
abcde
ab cd ef
abcdefg

The above is doing:

Decorate with awk: The awk command is decorating the input file by adding the number of non-blank chars and then the input line number before the original input line. I'm separating the awk output fields with tabs as that's a default separator value for both of the subsequent commands in the pipeline, sort and cut.
Sort with sort - I'm sorting using the number of non-spaces first and then the original line number second so that if 2 lines have the same number of characters they retain their input order in the output
Undecorate with cut - I'm just printing from the 3rd tab-separated field on, which takes us back to the original input line.

To see how that works, just add the commands one at a time:
$ cat file
a b c
abcde
ab cd ef
abcdefg
a
a b


$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{print length() - gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"&"), NR, $0}' file
3       1       a b c
5       2       abcde
6       3       ab cd ef
7       4       abcdefg
1       5       a
2       6       a b


$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{print length() - gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"&"), NR, $0}' file | sort -n -k1,1 -k2,2
1       5       a
2       6       a b
3       1       a b c
5       2       abcde
6       3       ab cd ef
7       4       abcdefg


$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{print length() - gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"&"), NR, $0}' file | sort -n -k1,1 -k2,2 | cut -f3-
a
a b
a b c
abcde
ab cd ef
abcdefg


I had never heard of this Decorate-sort-undecorate idiom before. Thanks so much for that great explanation.

You're welcome. The idiom originated in Lisp and one day on usenet a programmer named Randall Schwartz used it when solving a problem using perl and then the perl-ites jumped all over it in awe and named it a "Schwartzian Transform" so unfortunately you may also hear people use that term when talking about this idiom in general even though that was just a perl implementation of the idiom.

Tweaking OP's current awk code to use gsub() to count the number of non white space characters:
awk '{ x=$0; print gsub(/[^[:space:]]/,"",x), $0 }' file.txt | sort

Where:

x=$0 - make copy of current line; we'll modify the copy while leaving the current line alone
gsub(...,x) - run gsub() against x (copy of $0)
NOTE - this will also ignore tabs; if OP wants to count tabs then replace /[^[:space:]]/ with /[^ ]/ (a single space)

We'll also need to make a tweak to allow sort to work properly when the count could be a variable number of digits.
Sample input:
$ cat file.txt
a b c
abcde
ab cd ef
abcdefg
a
a b
asdfasdfasdfas as       asdfasfdasdf       # that's a single tab (\t) between the 2nd and 3rd strings

Running with sort:
$ awk '{ x=$0; print gsub(/[^[:space:]]/,"",x), $0 }' file.txt | sort 
1 a
2 a b
28 asdfasdfasdfas as    asdfasfdasdf       # wrong; lexicographic/alphabetic ordering
3 a b c
5 abcde
6 ab cd ef
7 abcdefg

Running with sort -n:
$ awk '{ x=$0; print gsub(/[^[:space:]]/,"",x), $0 }' file.txt | sort -n
1 a
2 a b
3 a b c
5 abcde
6 ab cd ef
7 abcdefg
28 asdfasdfasdfas as    asdfasfdasdf       # right; numeric ordering

Counting tabs:
$ awk '{ x=$0; print gsub(/[^ ]/,"",x), $0 }' file.txt | sort -n
1 a
2 a b
3 a b c
5 abcde
6 ab cd ef
7 abcdefg
29 asdfasdfasdfas as    asdfasfdasdf       # +1 since we're counting the tab between 2nd and 3rd strings


$ sort <(awk -F'[^ ]' '{print NF-1,$0}' file)
1 a
2 a b
3 a b c
5 abcde
6 ab cd ef
7 abcdefg


Disclaimer this solution assumes lines in file.txt are unique, if this does not hold ignore this answer entirely.
I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way, let file.txt content be
a b c 
abcde
ab cd ef
abcdefg
a
a b

then
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[^[:space:]]";PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"}{arr[$0]=NF}END{for(i in arr){print arr[i],i}}' file.txt

gives output
1 a
2 a b
3 a b c 
6 ab cd ef
5 abcde
7 abcdefg

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that non-white-space character constitute field and to traverse array with ascending values as numbers. When processing lines I store number of fields (that is number of non-white-space characters) in array arr under key being said line. When that is done I traverse that array in desired output and output stored number followed by line.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

This might work for you (GNU sed, paste & sort):
sed 's/ //g;s/././g' file | paste - file | sort | sed 's/.*\t//'

Double the string on each line separating by a tab and reduce the first of these strings by removing any spaces and making the remaining characters uniform.
Sort the resulting file and then remove the introduced first string and tab of each line.
Another more complicated solution using the same ideas but in a single sed invocation:
sed -E 's/.*/&\t&/;:a;s/ (.*\t)/\1/;s/[^.](.*\t)/.\1/;ta;H;$!d
        x;s/.//;s/.*/echo "&"|sort/e;s/^.*\t//mg' file

N.B. If you want a stable sort used sort -k1,1 -s.

With perl:
$ perl -e 'print sort {length($a =~ s/ //gr) <=> length($b =~ s/ //gr)} <>' ip.txt
a
a b
a b c 
abcde
ab cd ef
abcdefg

With ruby:
$ ruby -e 'puts readlines.sort_by {_1.sub(" ", "").size}' ip.txt
a
a b
a b c 
abcde
ab cd ef
abcdefg


This pure Bash solution might be of interest:
while read -r line; do t=${line//[[:space:]]/}; lines[${#t}]+="$line"$'\n'; done <file.txt; printf '%s' "${lines[@]}"


It is only practical for small input files (maybe up to 10 thousand lines).  Pure Bash code is too slow for processing large amounts of data line-by-line.
It depends on the fact that Bash arrays are sparse (so any index can be assigned without assigning anything to lower indices) and that the contents of Bash arrays are expanded in order by index values.  This avoids the need for doing explicit sorting in the code.
The code will drop the last line of the input file if it does not have a terminating newline.  This is easy to fix, but the code is just a curiosity so I didn't bother.  See the My text files are broken! They lack their final newlines! section of BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?) if you are interested.

